# Use a complex custom sort in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, sorting

I can't find how to add custom sorting to WPF ListView control? I don't need to sort by columns asc or desc, I need a custom one with some algorithm in it?

can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: use ObservableCollection as ItemsSource and sort your collection in whatever logic you want... it will reflect on UI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CustomSort` property on `ListCollectionView` provided that you implement `IComparer` for your class:

```
//somewhere in code behind of your window:
var view = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items); //Items is an ObservableCollection<T> 
view.CustomSort = new MyComparer(); //MyComparable implements IComparer
```

Any control bound to your Items such as ListBox will display elements in order.

Comment: There was a problem with this method as I remember.. But now it seems like ok. Thank you!